# SQL Server if condition NULL checking

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written SQL Server procedure like below,

```
if @name_belongs_to != 'John'
begin
  --doing some operation
end
```

If the name is not 'John', it is working fine. However if it is NULL, it is not executing if part.

How to handle this?

Comment: This is a symptom of three valued logic, read here for more information; https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use `COALESECE()` on the name:

```
if coalesce(@name_belongs_to, '') != 'John'
begin
  --doing some operation
end
```

You cannot compare `NULL` values in SQL Server (and most other RDBMS) using the equals operator.  Instead, you need to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  Using `COALESCE()` here is a trick which will convert a `NULL` value to a string for comparison with `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

This is also valid:

```
if @name_belongs_to != 'John' OR @name_belongs_to IS NULL
begin
  --doing some operation
end
```

This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138(v=vs.110).aspx) explains how Three-Valued Logic works.

Answer (score 0):

just use is not null

```
if @name_belongs_to != 'John' or @name_belongs_to is not  null
begin
  --doing some operation
end
```

Answer (score 0):

By default any comparison to null returns false

null = null is false
null = 'value' is false

so you need to add

```
OR @name_belongs_to IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below statement to resolve my issue,

```
if isnull(@name_belongs_to,'') != 'John'
```